# how to make a firebase query on flask(python)?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database

I've been making an application for translating the menu(Kor to Eng) 
but I have a problem.

I've stored data on firebase(realtime database) cause there are lots of mistranslation if I only use translator.

[image: my database]

I can successfully bring the data using :

```
ref = db.reference('data').child('jaZWAoZQn6yKbOERUtL2')
```

What I want to do is I have a specific Korean word then search it on the child nodes and if the word exists, I want to receive English word (obviously it's also stored on database).

The problem is I know that I have to use `'equal_to'` and `'order_by_child'` before using `'equal_to'`, but the child is the number(0,1,...) so there is no meaning to do this.

I can approach each korName and engName but I have no idea how to find korName which equals the value I'll give to and bring me back the engName.

Should I use **for loop** for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
ref = db.reference('data').child('jaZWAoZQn6yKbOERUtL2')
```

You can find the child nodes with a specific value in their `korName` property under that with:

```
query = ref.order_by_child('korName').equal_to('the_value_you_want')
snapshot = query.get()
for key in snapshot:
    print(key)
```

Comment: Actually I tried that before but I got an error :
firebase_admin.exceptions.InvalidArgumentError: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "korName", for path "/data/jaZWAoZQn6yKbOERUtL2", to the rules

Comment: You'll need to define an index on `korName` in your database's security rules under path `"/data/jaZWAoZQn6yKbOERUtL2"`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data Please learn to search on error messages, as this has been asked before: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+Index+not+defined%2C+add+%22.indexOn%22

Comment: Thank you so much. I thougth I searched enough but now I realized I'm a bit lazy to do.. 
Hope you have a great day!!